# Django Integrating Python Social Auth And The Default Auth With A Custom User Model:

Tags: django, facebook-authentication, python-social-auth

I have a project I am working on that requires some users to be authenticated via facebook and others to sign up using a custom model. The facebook users will not have the same sign up credentials as the custom model. For example- there will be a restaurant owner sign up and a customer signup. The customer will not have to put a street address location, they can simply login.

My intentions were to have the restaurant owners sign up via the custom profile model and the facebook users to simply login via the defualt social auth, but whenever I combine the two, social auth starts to use the custom model because I define a custom user model within settings. Is there a way to distinguish to the python social auth backend to only use the default or a way to update my current custom user model to have a facebook segment. I have searched the web for a long time for this, but can not seem to find anything that can combine the two besides (1), but it did not work successfully. I can however get one or the other working successfully depending on if I specify a user model in my settings.py file or not.

It is quite simple, but I do not know of a way to get social auth to look at its default and djangos authentication to look at my custom model.

(1)-http://code.techandstartup.com/django/profiles/

Answer (score 2):

In order to distinguish one type of user from another, you can do something like this:

**First**, in your settings file, store the following:

```
FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['type']
```

This will be stored in `strategy` parameter in every function of pipeline

**Then**, change the pipeline wherever necessary. For example, in your `create_user` pipeline function, you can do this:

```
user_type = strategy.session_get('type')

if user_type != 'customuser':
    return {
        'is_new': True,
        'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)
    }
else:
    return {
        'is_new': True,
        'user': create_restaurant(**fields)
    }
```